# How to successfully unload a swf, and go to parent swf, after pressing the exit button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Using a code snippet in [as3](/questions/tagged/as3) [flash](/questions/tagged/flash), but struggling for it to actually work:

I would like to unload the child `SWF` (which is a video) and go back into the parent `SWF` (a video selection page). Tried so many different ways and need a quick and easy solution. Thanks.

Below does not seem to work...

```
exit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF);

import fl.display.ProLoader;
var fl_ProLoader:ProLoader;

//This variable keeps track of whether you want to load or unload the SWF

var fl_ToLoad:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    fl_ProLoader.unload();
    removeChild(fl_ProLoader);
    fl_ProLoader = null;
}
```

Comment: How the `fl_ToLoad ` keeps track of whether you want to load or unload the `SWF`? Complete all your code, maybe the error is in other part.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code it's tested

```
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.*;

var _file: File;
_file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("./Directory to swf file/mySwf.swf");
if (_file.exists) {
    trace("SWF loading ...........");
    displayingSWF(_file.nativePath)
} else {
    trace("the file doesn't exit");
}



//////////////// DIsplay the SWF story file //////////////////
var mLoader: Loader ;
function displayingSWF(lnk) {
    var inFileStream: FileStream = new FileStream();
    inFileStream.open(_file, FileMode.READ);
    var swfBytes: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    inFileStream.readBytes(swfBytes);
    inFileStream.close();

 mLoader = new Loader();
    var loaderContext: LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
    loaderContext.allowCodeImport = true;
      mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfLoadComplete);
     mLoader.loadBytes(swfBytes, loaderContext);     
}

function onSwfLoadComplete(e: Event): void {
         mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfLoadComplete);
        addChild(mLoader);
    }
exit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dimising);

function dimising(e: MouseEvent): void {
    mLoader.unloadAndStop();
    removeChild(mLoader);

}
```

Comment: I tried that, did not work... is the rest of the code right?... the button is called exit_btn. Do I need to add anything or remove anythingelse? Thanks